# Abstract problem involving implicit function theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-function-theorem

Let $W = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; x,y>0\}$ and $z:W\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a positive $\mathcal{C}^1$ function. Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ also  $\mathcal{C}^1$ function so that $F \left(x+\frac{z(x,y)}{y}, y+ \frac{z(x,y)}{x} \right) =0$ for any $(x,y) \in W$. And $\nabla F\neq 0$ in the entire plane.
I need to prove that $$x\frac{ \partial z }{\partial x} + y\frac{ \partial z }{\partial y} = z-xy$$

I tried to expressing $y$ as a function of $x$ : $y=g(x)$ where $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \neq 0$. so $g'(x)= -\left[\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} (x,g(x))\right]^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,g(x))$ but I don't think it's going anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
$$\Phi(x,y):=F\left(x+{z(x,y)\over y}, y+{z(x,y)\over x}\right)$$is $\equiv0$ on $W$. It follows that
$$\eqalign{
\Phi_x&=F_{.1}\left(1+{z_x\over y}\right)+F_{.2}\left({z_x\over x}-{z\over x^2}\right)\equiv0\cr
\Phi_y&=F_{.1}\left({z_y\over y}-{z\over y^2}\right)+F_{.2}\left(1+{z_y\over x}\right)\equiv0\cr}\tag{1}$$
in $W$. Since by assumption $\bigl(F_{.1}(u,v), F_{.2}(u,v)\bigr)=\nabla F(u,v)\ne(0,0)$ for all $(u,v)$ it follows that the determinant of the homogeneous system $(1)$ for the unknowns $F_{.1}$, $F_{.2}$ has to vanish identically:
$$\left(1+{z_x\over y}\right)\left(1+{z_y\over x}\right)-\left({z_x\over x}-{z\over x^2}\right)\left({z_y\over y}-{z\over y^2}\right)=0\ .$$
Clearing  denominators we get
$$x^2y^2-z^2+(x^2y+xz)z_x+(xy^2+zy)z_y=0\ .$$
Here you can factor out $xy+z>0$ to obtain the stated relation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the statement :"the determinant of the system (1) has to vanish identically". Maybe it's just my *** English preventing my from seeing what you mean.

Comment: For an homogeneus system, if there is one only solution, this is zero for all the unknowns. Conversely, if at least one of the unknowns is not zero, one equation is linear combination of the others. Being so, the determinant of the coeficients must vanish. By other side, I was looking to manipulate the function $F$ "as is" but ended with precisely that system of equations. I didn't realize it isn't necesary solve it to solve the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

We can set $F(u,v)=0$ and because $\nabla F\ne 0$, by the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#The_circle_example) there exists $f$ such that:

$$u=f(v);\;\text{and then}\;x+\frac{z}{y}=f(y+\frac{z}{x})$$

We can now derive with respect to $x$ and respecto to $y$. As long $f=f(v)$, $f'$ stands for $\mathrm df/\mathrm dv$.

$$\left\{\begin{array}{1}
   1+\dfrac{z_x}{y}=\left(\dfrac{z_x}{x}-\dfrac{z}{x^2}\right)f'\\
   \dfrac{z_y}{y}-\dfrac{z}{y^2}=\left(1+\dfrac{z_y}{x}\right)f'
\end{array}\right.$$

$$\left\{\begin{array}{1}
   1+\dfrac{z_x}{y}=f'\dfrac{z_x}{x}-f'\dfrac{z}{x^2} \\
   \dfrac{z_y}{y}-\dfrac{z}{y^2}=f'+f'\dfrac{z_y}{x}
\end{array}\right.$$

$$\left\{\begin{array}{1}
   \dfrac{z_x}{y}-f'\dfrac{z_x}{x}=-1-f'\dfrac{z}{x^2} \\
   \dfrac{z_y}{y}-f'\dfrac{z_y}{x}=f'+\dfrac{z}{y^2}
\end{array}\right.$$

$$\left\{\begin{array}{1}
   z_x\left(1/y-f'/x\right)=-1-f'\dfrac{z}{x^2} \\
   z_y\left(1/y-f'/x\right)=f'+\dfrac{z}{y^2}
\end{array}\right.$$

$$\left\{\begin{array}{1}
   z_x=\dfrac{-1-f'z/x^2}{1/y-f'/x}\\
   z_y=\dfrac{f'+z/y^2}{1/y-f'/x}
\end{array}\right.$$

We can now try to write $xz_x+yz_y$ with the expressions we've got:

$$xz_x+yz_y=x\dfrac{-1-f'z/x^2}{1/y-f'/x}+y\dfrac{f'+z/y^2}{1/y-f'/x}=$$

$$=\dfrac{-x-f'zx/x^2+yf'-yz/y^2}{1/y-f'/x}=\dfrac{z(1/y-f'/x)-xy(f'/x-1/y)}{1/y-f'/x}=$$

$$=(z-xy)(1/y-f'/x)/(1/y-f'/x)=z-xy$$

So is:

$$xz_x+yz_y=z-xy$$

Furthermore, solving this pde we find that $F \left(x+\frac{z(x,y)}{y}, y+ \frac{z(x,y)}{x} \right) =0$ is its the general solution.

Comment: I think I miss something in your answer: To my understanding, $\nabla F \neq 0$ does not imply $\frac {\partial F}{\partial x} \neq 0 $ and $\frac {\partial F}{\partial y} \neq 0 $ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, so the function $f$ you describe, exists on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ but not necessarily the whole real line. I think I can see how to fix this but I'll be very glad to accept your answer after you will.
Thanks!

Comment: You can set $G(u,v)=u-f(v)=0$ as $f$ exists for the entire plane. $\nabla G\ne0, too$